# How do I find out when a Virtualbox VM is ready to accept SSH connections?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I'm writing a simple script that creates a new VirtualBox VM, spins it up and then connects to it via SSH to execute some commands. The problem is, I have to wait for a certain amount of time for the VM to boot. Currently I just do a `sleep 120` in my script to sleep for 2 minutes. However, instead of waiting for 2 minutes, I would like to get some sort of notification when the VM boots and is ready to accept SSH connections. Is that possible?

P.S.:
Solutions involving guest additions won't work - the OS on the guest is vanilla CentOS 5.7, no guest additions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the `sleep 120` with something like

```
while :; do
  ssh guest && break
  sleep 10
done
```

to just keep trying until you got through.

Answer (score 0):

I do this a lot with my notify-when-up2 script:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/notify-when-up2.html

It'll give you an e-mail and a popup window when a port starts accepting connections, among other things.

EG:
notify-when-up2 -n remote.host.com 22